# Unique constraint on SQL insert -ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Im running a script which would fire a select query and insert the results into a table.

The select query is

```
select distinct a.child child_id, a.parent parent_id from cat a, par b WHERE a.child=b.catentid and b.catenttype_id='Product' and a.reltype_id='PRODUCT_ITEM'
```

and inserted into the table which is created as

```
create table TI_CAT_0 ( child_id NUMBER not null,parent_id NUMBER not null,PRIMARY KEY (child_id))
```

But I get a unique key constraint violation while running the script as "SYS_C00187123", and I checked this constraint name in all_constraints table and its on the TI_CAT_0 table only.

Since I use the distinct command, I'm not sure why this violation is turning up. Its a Oracle DB.

Comment: are you sure the `child_id` you're selecting doesn't already exist in `TI_CAT_0` table

Comment: distinct operates on **all** columns of the select, not  just the first one. So you can have the same value for `child_id` with different values for `parent_id` and it would still be distinct.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So any way we can have the distinct child id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are creating the `TI_CAT_0` table from scratch and inserting records from your `SELECT` query, then you are either unintentionally inserting the same record more than once, or your initial query is returning multiple rows for each `child_id`. If this is the case, you should run this query to see if your initial query is returning duplicate `child_id` values.  Your query, as it is written, will return unique combinations of `child_id` and `parent_id`.  You can check to see if multiple parents are associated with a single child with the following SQL:

```
select 
    a.child, 
    count(a.parent) as parent_count
from 
    cat a
    join par b 
        on a.child = b.catentid 
where 
    b.catenttype_id='Product' 
    and a.reltype_id='PRODUCT_ITEM'
group by 
    a.child
having
    count(a.parent) > 1
order by 2 desc
```

The results (if any) will be all `child_id` values associated with multiple `parent_id` values.